# Linearizing a DAG with multiple sources

Tags: algorithm, theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am looking at my algorithms book, and I see there is a simple algorithm to linearize a single source, directed acyclic graph by deleting source nodes one by one. Can someone give me an example for why this would not work for multiple sources?

Comment: This question may get better traction on [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Are you referring to topological sorting?

Comment: Yup, topological sorting.

Comment: It works if there are multiple source nodes. Just pick any.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can topo sort a generalized DAG that consists of any number of distinct components that are simple DAGs with the source removal algorithm.

The proof is not hard. You should try it for yourself. If you can't get it, ask and I'll give an outline.

But there's a simpler way to do topo sort. Connect a new master source node to all DAG sources with single edges, then do a depth first search from the master source, applying node numbers in post order (that is, number each node consecutively *after* all its descendants have been visited). The master source gets the highest number. Ignore this one. The remaining node numbers give a topo sort in reverse order.

I.e. there is no need to deconstruct the graph as in the source removal algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "linearize" you mean converting the graph to a sequence of nodes by a one-to-one mapping, such that the full graph can be recovered.

A single-source DAG is just a directed forest. You can linearize it, for example, by [pre-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order), just like a tree, starting from each root sequentially.

For example, this graph:

[image: DAG with single-source]

Becomes `(a (b c)) (e f g)`.

The problem with general DAGs is that you may have to repeat the same node more than once:

[image: DAG with multiple sources]

Will become `(a (b c)) (e (b c) f g)`, and then when you reconstruct the graph, you may get:

[image: Reconstructed DAG]

Unless you handle duplicates specifically. You could linearize to just `(a (b c)) (e b f g)` and solve the problem by remembering nodes you already reconstructed, though.

Anyway, I suppose that using your node deletion algorithm, you would remove `b` here on the first encounter, so that you won't be able to reach it from `e`, and you'll get just `(a (b c)) (e f g)` which is wrong.

Comment: He's talking about topological sort, I think.

Comment: @Gene right, now I saw his comment. This notion of linearization was useful for me, though, so I shared my answer for anyone else who might need it too :)

Answer (score 0):

I do believe, that if you revert the edges on the original graph and run a DFS (depth first search from the previously sink node, made source by the reversion, you will get the reverse topological order in which to linearize the original graph. This is just an intuition though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).